# How to wrap text in ag-grid from a checkbox

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid angular compnent and need a functionality to wrap text in cell that needs to be controlled from a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `cellClassRules` to column:-

```
 cellClassRules: {
      'wrap-text': params => {
        return params.data.checkboxColumn === true;
      },
     'no-wrap-text': params => {
        return !params.data.checkboxColumn;
      }
    },
```

## or, checkbox is outside

1. Store info in an array

   this.checkBoxInfo = [];  // use api.refreshCells({force:true})

   ```
    cellClassRules: {
         'wrap-text': params => {
             // add condition using `this.checkBoxInfo` and return 
                              //   true/false
               return  true/false;
           },
       'no-wrap-text': params => {
               // add condition using `this.checkBoxInfo` and return 
              //   true/false
               return  true/false;
          }
      },
   ```

Comment: Its for all rows & columns and checkbox is outisde of ag-grid.

Comment: Updated...you need to store your conditional info in an array .